Selecting grouped samples satisfying desired conditions
I have a dataframe like
raw.df <- data.frame(id = c("X01", "X02", "X03", "X04", "X05", "X06", "X07", "X08", "X09", "X10"),
           subject = c("S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S04", "S05", "S06"),
           time = c("D0", "D1", "D2", "D0", "D2", "D0", "D0", "D2", "D2", "D2"),
           response = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))

I want to create a new column to add "Y" for the samples satisfying conditions, and "N" for the others. If any subject with response="Y" has two samples from times D0 and D2, they should be selected. Based on that, I need to obtain the dataframe below with "selected" column.
final.df <- data.frame(id = c("X01", "X02", "X03", "X04", "X05", "X06", "X07", "X08", "X09", "X10"),
           subject = c("S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S04", "S05", "S06"),
           time = c("D0", "D1", "D2", "D0", "D2", "D0", "D0", "D2", "D2", "D2"),
           response = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"),
           selected = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N"))

I can select samples without pairing using case_when by;
final.df <- raw.df %>%
  mutate(selected = case_when(time %in% c("D0", "D2") & response = "Y" ~ "Y",
                              TRUE ~ "N"))

for pairing, I can use another code
final.df %>%
  filter(selected == "Y") %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  add_count() %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(n = if_else(n == 2, "Include", "Exclude")) %>%
  dplyr::rename(`paired` = n) 

and then I can combine those, but I wonder if there is a better combined solution

What do you mean by selected rows that are paired by subject id?

What exactly did you try? case_when or if_else should do the trick here.

You need to give more context as your problem statement is rather vague.

@IfeanyiIdiaye I edited my question, hope it is more clear now

One way could be to create a table of matching cases and join to it. The matching cases where are where time is D0 or D1, response is Y, and there are two distinct times per subject -- ie at least one Y for each of those two times. Then I put in N where the join doesn't have a match.
raw.df |>
  left_join(
    raw.df |>
      filter(time %in% c("D0", "D2"), response == "Y") |>
      distinct(time, subject) |>
      filter(n() == 2, .by = subject) |>
      mutate(selected = "Y")) |>
  mutate(selected = coalesce(selected, "N"))

Result
    id subject time response selected
1  X01     S01   D0        Y        Y
2  X02     S01   D1        Y        N
3  X03     S01   D2        Y        Y
4  X04     S02   D0        N        N
5  X05     S02   D2        N        N
6  X06     S03   D0        Y        N
7  X07     S04   D0        Y        Y
8  X08     S04   D2        Y        Y
9  X09     S05   D2        Y        N
10 X10     S06   D2        N        N


Here's another option using case_when followed by filter. My assumption was that your final data is supposed to only contain the rows you flagged as "include":
library(tidyverse)
raw.df |> 
  mutate(selected = case_when(response == "Y" & any(time == "D0") & any(time == "D2") ~ "Y",
                              TRUE ~ "N"), .by = subject) |> 
  filter(selected == "Y" & time %in% c("D0", "D2"))

   id subject time response selected
1 X01     S01   D0        Y        Y
2 X03     S01   D2        Y        Y
3 X07     S04   D0        Y        Y
4 X08     S04   D2        Y        Y

Technically, you don't even need the mutate step and instead could put everything together into one filter condition:
raw.df |> 
  filter(response == "Y" & any(time == "D0") & any(time == "D2") & time %in% c("D0", "D2"), .by = subject)

   id subject time response
1 X01     S01   D0        Y
2 X03     S01   D2        Y
3 X07     S04   D0        Y
4 X08     S04   D2        Y

If, however, you want to keep all rows and flag them with Y/N:
raw.df |> 
  mutate(selected = case_when(response == "Y" & any(time == "D0") & any(time == "D2") & time %in% c("D0", "D2") ~ "Y",
                              TRUE  ~ "N"), .by = subject)

    id subject time response selected
1  X01     S01   D0        Y        Y
2  X02     S01   D1        Y        N
3  X03     S01   D2        Y        Y
4  X04     S02   D0        N        N
5  X05     S02   D2        N        N
6  X06     S03   D0        Y        N
7  X07     S04   D0        Y        Y
8  X08     S04   D2        Y        Y
9  X09     S05   D2        Y        N
10 X10     S06   D2        N        N


An base alternative using by() + within():
by(raw.df[-2], raw.df[2], \(x) within(x, { selected
  = ifelse(response=="Y" & any(time=="D0") & any(time=="D2") & time!="D1", "Y", "N")
  })) |> array2DF() |> `row.names<-`(NULL)

giving
   subject  id time response selected
1      S01 X01   D0        Y        Y
2      S01 X02   D1        Y        N
3      S01 X03   D2        Y        Y
4      S02 X04   D0        N        N
5      S02 X05   D2        N        N
6      S03 X06   D0        Y        N
7      S04 X07   D0        Y        Y
8      S04 X08   D2        Y        Y
9      S05 X09   D2        Y        N
10     S06 X10   D2        N        N

or
tapply(raw.df[-2], raw.df[2], transform, 
       selected = response=="Y" & any(time=="D0") & any(time=="D2") & time!="D1") |>
  array2DF()

Using logical TRUE/FALSE instead of character Y/N is generally preferred and often simplifies further analysis.
